# Refresh DataGridView with another select query

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to be able to choose a view in my application, where one selection should get all rows where Imported = 1, and the other selection should get only Imported = 0. I just started learning this, so i went with an example from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control But i didnt want all columns in the database and i also wanted to have certain widths on some columns, so i added the column code and it has been working great. But when i try to do a new GetData it doesnt refresh, it adds records instead. The GetData as a refresh works great in Microsofts example, so im guessing this has something to do with the way i made the columns in the datagridview. What am i doing wrong with my code? btnZendeskImport_Click is the refresh in this case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadDGW();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
            GetData("select TicketID,Customer,Subject,ticketTime,ticketDate,Assignee,ProjectType,SupportAgreement,Imported from Ticketslabb WHERE Imported = 1");
            testLabel.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();
        }
        private void GetData(string selectCommand)
        {
            try
            {
                // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
                // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
                // database accessible to your system.
                String connectionString =
                    "Data Source=LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                              "Initial Catalog=ticketDB;" +
                              "Integrated Security=SSPI;";

                // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

                // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
                // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
                // update the database.
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.

                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

                // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
                //dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
                //    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("To run this example, replace the value of the " +
                    "connectionString variable with a connection string that is " +
                    "valid for your system.");
            }
        }
        private void reloadButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //Reload the data from the database.
            GetData(dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText);
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString());
        }
        private void searchTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("CONVERT({0}, System.String) like '%{1}%' OR Subject like '%{1}%' OR Customer like '%{1}%'", "TicketID", searchTxtBox.Text);
        }
        private void LoadDGW()
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(

                new cbComponent.GridViewCheckBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
                new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn());

            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketCheckbox = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketID = dataGridView1.Columns[1];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketCustomer = dataGridView1.Columns[2];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketSubject = dataGridView1.Columns[3];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketTime = dataGridView1.Columns[4];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketDate = dataGridView1.Columns[5];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketAgent = dataGridView1.Columns[6];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketProjectType = dataGridView1.Columns[7];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketSupportAgreement = dataGridView1.Columns[8];
            DataGridViewColumn dgwTicketImported = dataGridView1.Columns[9];


            dgwTicketCheckbox.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dgwTicketCheckbox.Width = 30;

            dgwTicketID.Name = "dgwTicketID";
            dgwTicketID.HeaderText = "ID";
            dgwTicketID.DataPropertyName = "TicketID";
            dgwTicketID.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dgwTicketID.Width = 50;

            dgwTicketCustomer.Name = "dgwTicketCustomer";
            dgwTicketCustomer.HeaderText = "Kund";
            dgwTicketCustomer.DataPropertyName = "Customer";
            dgwTicketCustomer.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dgwTicketCustomer.Width = 210;

            dgwTicketSubject.Name = "dgwTicketSubject";
            dgwTicketSubject.HeaderText = "Ämne";
            dgwTicketSubject.DataPropertyName = "Subject";
            dgwTicketSubject.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dgwTicketSubject.Width = 420;

            dgwTicketTime.Name = "dgwTicketTime";
            dgwTicketTime.HeaderText = "Tid";
            dgwTicketTime.DataPropertyName = "ticketTime";
            dgwTicketTime.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dgwTicketTime.Width = 40;

            dgwTicketDate.Name = "dgwTicketDate";
            dgwTicketDate.HeaderText = "Datum";
            dgwTicketDate.DataPropertyName = "ticketDate";

            dgwTicketAgent.Name = "dgwTicketAgent";
            dgwTicketAgent.HeaderText = "Agent";
            dgwTicketAgent.DataPropertyName = "Assignee";

            dgwTicketProjectType.Name = "dgwProjectType";
            dgwTicketProjectType.DataPropertyName = "ProjectType";
            dgwTicketProjectType.Visible = false;


            dgwTicketSupportAgreement.Name = "dgwTicketSupportAgreement";
            dgwTicketSupportAgreement.DataPropertyName = "SupportAgreement";
            dgwTicketSupportAgreement.Visible = false;

            dgwTicketImported.Name = "dgwTicketImported";
            dgwTicketImported.DataPropertyName = "Imported";
            dgwTicketImported.Visible = false;

            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
            this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        }

        private void btnVismaChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<DataGridViewRow> rows_with_checked_column = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
                {
                    var builder = new StringBuilder();
                    row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                   .ToList().ForEach(cell =>
                                   {
                                       if (cell.ColumnIndex != 0)
                                       {
                                           builder.Append(string.Format("{0} ", cell.Value));
                                       }
                                   });
                    rows_with_checked_column.Add(row);
                    MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void cbView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnZendeskImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GetData("select TicketID,Customer,Subject,ticketTime,ticketDate,Assignee,ProjectType,SupportAgreement,Imported from Ticketslabb WHERE Imported = 0");
            testLabel.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dataAdapter.Fill(table);` Fills the table as the name suggests.  it is not a refresh and using a new query is not a refresh. A new/different query requires that you use a new DataTable.  If you dont want all columns, omit them from the SQL rather than add the desired columns manually.  You can also resize them as desired rather than add them all manually.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: So Why does the Microsoft exempel work just as i want it to and my code does not?

Comment: Because *you* changed the code.  The MS code creates a **new** `DataTable` each time in GetData; you dont.  Which is what *A new/different query requires that you use a new DataTable* means.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that i edited the GetData function after adding the search function. Now it works!